# How to SUM (logical AND) boolean values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in Mysql with multiple columns. One of them is boolean.

```
SELECT sum(plan) as plan, sum(consumo) as consumo, energia.fecha 
FROM energia 
INNER JOIN servicios ON (energia.id_serv=servicios.id) 
INNER JOIN usuario_servicio ON (servicios.id=usuario_servicio.id_servicio) 
WHERE YEAR(fecha) = ? AND MONTH(fecha) = ? AND usuario_servicio.id_usuario = ? 
GROUP BY energia.fecha;
```

I need to include in the `SELECT` a value that returns false if one of the grouped values of that column are false (similar to logical AND). I tried to use the `SUM` function, but it returns a number.

Comment: *if one of the grouped values of that column ...* of which column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Boolean as just ones and zeros, you van use MAX(boolField) for OR or MIN(boolField) for AND if the values cannot be NULL.